# Problema con el editor de código en Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

alguien sabe porque cuando salto de línea (oprimo <kbd>Enter ↲</kbd>) en NetBeans no hace el "auto Tab"? Solo se queda al inicio de la línea en lugar de que quede entre los corchetes.
Al hacer el formateo del código pierdo un poco de productividad

[image: queda de la siguiente manera]

Debería hacer esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Acabo de probar con Apache NetBeans IDE 12.6 y no pude reproducir tu problema, tal vez quieras especificar la version de netbeans